# Error casting soap XML to BankData type

Tags: yodlee

Just starting to investigate the Yodlee soap example and I am having problems with an

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlNode[]' to type 'BankData'.

error in the DisplayBankData class. I have tried downloading and creating the Yodlee dll from the wdsl definitions from 2014Q3WSDLs as well as using the DLL that came with the download with no success. The same problem is also happening with the CardData class (and possibly others)

Am I missing something or is there a problem with the wsdl definitions supplied?

Answer (score 0):

After spending many hours trying to work out whats going on here, I have finally worked out that there is something wrong with either the WDSL files generated by Yodlee, or the way that WSDL.exe interprets the WSDL files.

The actual cause of it is because the WSDL does not seem to indicate what type is returned under ItemData1.Accounts, this is because it can be either BankData or CardData, since VisualStudio does not know what type to expect, it de-serialises the object as an XML node.

The way I have managed to get round this is when you use the WSDL.exe to produce the yodleeProxies.vb file, you will need to go into the generated file and then find the defenition for the ItemData1 Class

```
Partial Public Class ItemData1
```

You will need to change

```
 Public Property accounts As Object()
```

to

```
Public Property accounts As BankData()
```

Then it knows that the object will be of type BankData

I have also added a new property that expects CardData so that CardData will appear under this one, and will de-serialise correctly

```
Public Property accounts2 As CardData()
    Get
        Return Me.accountsField
    End Get
    Set(value As CardData())
        Me.accountsField = value
    End Set
End Property
```

So thats my hack on how to resolve it, if any one else has worked out a more elegant way of getting round this, please do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I found adding the XmlInclude() attribute below to the ItemData1 class in the proxy file [glyn johnston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4786307/glyn-johnston) mentioned solves the issue - apparently the deserializer doesn't know to consider ItemAccountData and its descendants when deserializing that property.

I believe 'accounts' should be kept as an array of objects as there are several types that inherit from ItemAccountData including CardData, BankData and others, and upon inspecting the WSDL directly 'accounts' appears to be defined as a 'List' of type 'anyType'.

It is possible it is defined this way to allow for adding newer types in the future without causing de-serialization issues, so basically you need to inspect each element in the array and determine its type individually, ignoring the types you do not know or care about.

```
...
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(typeof(ItemAccountData))]
public partial class ItemData1 {
...
```

I believe the source of the problem is the Xml deserializer doesn't consider types that aren't somehow tied to the definition of the class ItemData1 via its method signatures, properties etc. and the XmlInclude() is the attribute to use to fix that.